# store list values in data.frame with unequal rows

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

I am trying to create a data-frame by extracting the values from the lists. I have a 157 list which contains unequal values, as shown in this pic

[image]

and what I want is to rbind all the list values in one data frame. I tried to do it through for loop but it only stored the first list values.
What I could do is:

```
   porturn1=data.table::rbindlist(lapply(porturn[1], as.data.frame), idcol = "id")
   porturn2=data.table::rbindlist(lapply(porturn[2], as.data.frame), idcol = "id")
   porturn3=data.table::rbindlist(lapply(porturn[3], as.data.frame), idcol = "id")
   porturn4=data.table::rbindlist(lapply(porturn[4], as.data.frame), idcol = "id")
   porturn5=data.table::rbindlist(lapply(porturn[5], as.data.frame), idcol = "id")
```

and then apply the `rbind.fill` command to all these data but it seems quite cumbersome and impractical. Though the result after `rbind.fill` is what I wanted, as shown in the pic:

[image: All values of first two lists]

How can I create a loop to create the required data frame(as shown in the last pic, I needed to store 157 list values or 157 rows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `do.call` with `rbind.fill`, which applies `rbind.fill` on individual entries of a `list` and assembles the results, in this case into a `data.frame`.

```
library(plyr)

## make test data
set.seed(0)
porturn <- sapply(sample(1:20, 10), function(x) 1:x)
str(porturn)
#> List of 10
#>  $ : int [1:18] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>  $ : int [1:6] 1 2 3 4 5 6
#>  $ : int [1:7] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
#>  $ : int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>  $ : int [1:15] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>  $ : int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
#>  $ : int [1:13] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>  $ : int [1:14] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>  $ : int [1:8] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
#>  $ : int [1:20] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

## work
porturnall = do.call(rbind.fill,lapply(porturn, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x))))
print(porturnall)
#>    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20
#> 1   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  NA  NA
#> 2   1  2  3  4  5  6 NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 3   1  2  3  4  5  6  7 NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 4   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 5   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 6   1  2  3  4 NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 7   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 8   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 9   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20

## Created on 2018-07-21 by the reprex package (v0.2.0).
```

Comment: It worked as I wanted my data frame to be, Thanks a lot.